# RPC to send variable from server to client on client joing game Unity

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, rpc, spawning

I have this network script that works really well except for when I want to spawn a player at a different location. Im basing location on the number of current players connect. Right now the variable is updating right on the server so that good. But when a client joins the game, the player count for him is 0. I want to set that to the current number of players connected from the server variable. I was messing around with RPC functions but with no luck.

So this is what I have so far.

```
    var playerCount : int = 0;

    //player and jump master spawn componets
    var playerPrefab : GameObject;
    //spawn points
   var sp1: Transform;
    var sp2: Transform;
   var sp3: Transform;
   var sp4: Transform;

   var sp : Transform;


   function OnServerInitialized()
   {
 Debug.Log("Server initilized");
 playerCount++;
 spawnPlayer(sp1);

   }
   function OnPlayerConnected(networkPlayer:NetworkPlayer):void
   {
     Debug.Log (networkPlayer.guid + " connected");
     playerCount++;

     //spawnPlayer(sp2);
    //spawning player here does not work! Just a black screen no cam perhaps
   }

   function OnConnectedToServer()
   {
  //loop though every object in the game
    for(var go : GameObject in FindObjectsOfType(GameObject))
    {
        go.SendMessage("OnNetworkLoadedLevel", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
    }
    Debug.Log("Connected to server");
    Debug.Log("Player Count: " + playerCount);
    if(playerCount ==0)
    {
        sp = sp1;

    }
    if(playerCount ==1)
    {
        sp = sp2;

    }
    if(playerCount ==2)
    {
        sp = sp3;

    }
    if(playerCount ==4)
    {
        sp = sp4;

    }
    spawnPlayer(sp);

      }


    //spawn player prefab
    function spawnPlayer(SP : Transform)
    {
  Network.Instantiate(playerPrefab, SP.position, Quaternion.identity, 0);
}

    @RPC
   function SendPlayerCount(player : NetworkPlayer )
   {
  //send playercount to client from server
  networkView.RPC("assignvariableRPC",player,playerCount);
   }
    @RPC
    function RecivePlayerCount(count : int)
   {
//get playercount from server
//playerCount = playerCount;
playerCount = count;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

make a global invisible object with NetworkView + OnSerializeNetworkView

is that what you want?

Comment: Sorry for the late response got re tasked at work. So your saying just make it public then it should send? I was think that I had to do a RPC call or something to update the variable to everyone

Comment: you need a static GameObject with NetworkView, so every player have this GameObject, so you could invoke RPC via this GameObject~

Comment: try OnSerializeNetworkView. that's what you want if you just need to sync playerCount variable.